# Write/Read any object to/from Android memory

Tags: java, android

I'm currently writing to methods to:

- read object from memory
- write object to memory

I tried to save a String object and read it again, yet my code didn't work.

This is my code:

```
public void writeObjectToMemory(String filename, Object object) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = game.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(object);
            os.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void readObjectFromMemory(String filename, Object object) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = game.openFileInput(filename);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            object = is.readObject();
            is.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem, which part didnt work? Any stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote :

```
public void readObjectFromMemory(String filename, Object object) {
    //...
    object = is.readObject();
```

But `object` is only a copy of the argument you passed to the function. You can change that copy inside the method (as you do), but this will have no effect on the actual parameter.

You have to return your object instead :

```
public Object readObjectFromMemory(String filename) {
    FileInputStream fis;
    Object obj;
    try {
        fis = game.openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        obj = is.readObject();
        is.close();
    } 
    catch (...) {
        return null;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Read this for more details : http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/

Comment: Just out of interest, how would I change the value of the original value without returning anything?

Comment: The only way is to copy manually each field of the new object to the old one (which is a bad idea if you add/remove fields later). But you can't change the reference to the original object inside the method, only its fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code for anybody that is interested:

Note: When using the `readObjectFromMemory(String filename, Object object)` you will have to cast the returned object.

```
/**
     * <b><i>public void writeObjectToMemory(String filename, Object object)</i></b>
     * <br>
     * Since: API 1
     * <br>
     * <br>
     * Write a object to the phone's internal storage.
     * 
     * @param filename 
     * The name of the file you wish to write to.
     *
     *      
     */

    public void writeObjectToMemory(String filename, Object object) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = game.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(object);
            os.close();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object successfully written: " + filename);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        }

    }

    /**
     * <b><i>public Object readObjectFromMemory(String filename, Object object)</i></b>
     * <br>
     * Since: API 1
     * <br>
     * <br>
     * Read a object from the phone's internal storage.
     * 
     * @param filename 
     * The name of the file you wish to read from.
     *
     *      
     */

    public Object readObjectFromMemory(String filename, Object object) {
        Object defautObject = null;
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = game.openFileInput(filename);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            defautObject = is.readObject();
            is.close();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object successfully read: " + filename);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Object couldn't be opened: " + filename);

        }

        return defautObject;

    }
```